# Thus returning a JSX necessarily makes the function a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

I have simple code, I have a component called Feed with some props.

On the main content component called Articles I map through a js object and return Feed component

Now, everyone are using an anonymous function to do so.

```
<div>
{data.map(()=> <Feed/>))} (sorry if the syntax a bit wrong but you get the idea
</div>
```

now, I took the function that returns Feed outside the map function

```
function createFeed (feedData) {
   return <Feed props/>
}
```

and put it

```
<div>
{data.map(createFeed)} 
</div>
```

and it workds wonder, but, thus createFeed is also a component (so I need to change the name to CreateFeed) or is this just a function that return an object to a new array created by the map function thus it's only a function and not a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic here.

```
<div>{data.map(createFeed)}</div>
```

Is equivalent to:

```
<div>{ data.map(item => createFeed(item) }</div>
```

Since the `createFeed` function returns the component without adding any logic, you can just omit it and return the component. It's all the same.

Edit:

In your case, you're merely using the function as a factory, not as a functional component, so you could argue that it doesn't need to be capitalized.

That is, if you're sure that you won't use the function as a component in Jsx, this is not a problem. If you want to use it as Jsx, this causes a problem, which is documented here: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

If there is no use in having a factory function, I would omit it, but in the end choice is up to you.

Comment: I know it's equivalent, but, that's not what I asked.

Comment: Can you maybe rephrase your question, so I understand it better?

Comment: Yes, I will try.

My friend and I are having an argument, he says, my createFeed function is a component, thus I should change it to CreateFeed, but I argue that it's not, just because it has a return and a component on the same line doesnt mean it's a component.
My question is, is createFeed counted as a component or just a normal function?

I think it's a normal function because it's getting a callback from the map function and returns the component as an object to another list that get rendered but does not  render itself.

Comment: @PazBazak: `createFeed` does not return a *component* it returns an *element*. There is no real difference between the definition of a function that returns a React element and a functional component. The difference is mostly how they are used. If you use it as a component, like `<Foo />` then the function is actually called some time later (if it is called at all). If you call it as a function it is called right there and then. You only *have to* capitalize the name if you want to use it in JSX (`<CreateFeed />`) if not, then don't worry about it.